# How to bend circle in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I know there are tutorials that make able to bend a line or either create a new line, that is circled, but I really have a specific line, and I need to have it bend in half circle.

I found similiar effect on a game, and I was wondering if there was possibility to replicate it on GIMP.

[image: http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/9170/571946-kingdom_hearts_1.jpg]

Comment: Health one, the green.

Comment: @Dominic Yes, but I have precise length of bar, if I will make circle, I would be unable to guess the length (maybe r^2*3.14). But I am thinking of resolution that wouldnt require additional hmmm, performance.

Comment: Yes, you're basically talking about the [circumference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumference) which can be worked out with the formula `2πr`.

Comment: @Dominic Yet I wanted to avoid additional actions, so I thought maybe there was possibility of direct execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much easier to generate an open circle with a vector graphics application (e.g. Inkscape) but here's how to do this with **Gimp**:

1. Create circular selection:

   [image]
2. Choose *Select - Border* to generate a border selection with a given pixes size (here 20):

   [image]
3. Create square selection in selection subtract mode:

   [image]
4. Subtract the square selection from the bordered circle selection:

   [image]
5. Fill with desired color (or draw selection outlines):

   [image]

Comment: Yeah, I kinda know this... but thanks for help anyway.